# Using predicate to find if string value exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, predicate

I have a NSMutableArray of objects with tag attributes assigned to them.  I am trying to find if any of these objects have a tag assigned to them of the string value "a".

my code so far:

```
for (Object *object in self.array)
    {
        NSDictionary *attrs = [object propertyValue:@"attrs"];
        NSString *tag = attrs[@"tag"];
    }
```

Can I do something like:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a"];
NSArray *results = [self.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

not sure how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", @"a"];
NSArray  *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Use **'contains[c]'** instead of **'=='** if you want to perform case-insensitive search.
If you want to filter for any other property, replace 'tag' with that property name.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something more like :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.property_name contains[c] '%@'", @"a"];
NSArray  *result = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```